# How to enable validation like sweetalert on server side in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose, handlebars.js, sweetalert

I am trying to validate the upload field on submit on handlebar side. There is a form where there is one upload input field and one submit button. On clicking submitting i want validation on server side means in nodejs for the upload field if it is empty.

I am trying sweetalert npm package but not working.

Handlebar Code:

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/api/upload/{{this.commonID}}/{{this.status}}" method="post">
    <td>
      <input type="file" class="btn btn-outline-warning" name="FileUploadForClient" multiple />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
</td>
</form>
```

Nodejs side package install:

```
const swal = require('sweetalert');
```

and I am using the below swtalrt code in the route which is triggered on submit:

```
swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
```

but not popping up.

Let me know if it can be solved by this npm package or else I need another solution if you have please suggest.

Comment: SweetAlert is a client side ONLY library.It is used to display dialog boxes. NodeJS is server side so it cannot use this module

Comment: To be clear do you expect in the server for a pop up to appear ?

Comment: yes! like sweetalert does i want it in server side instead of using res.send().

Comment: Then what is the use of this package? npm install --save sweetalert Its there in npm.js site.

Comment: First of all. You can't just show a pop up on a server (NO UI). Second. Npm acts also like bower . You can install the dependencies and the using tools like babel and webpack to compile multiple js files into a single one. I imagine the latter is the case here

Comment: Also if you don't use `res.send`(or any method that will send an actual response to the user ` you will hang the user side